# user-security on firebase for login users

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to set rules that admin node can write & read all nodes of events,
Also user can read/write/create to his node.
My issue I am getting  permission denied when I am running my app.
My rules are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "events": {
       ".read": "root.child('admin').hasChild(auth.uid)",
       ".write": "root.child('admin').hasChild(auth.uid)",
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
         ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    },
```

My code :

```
 constructor(public af: AngularFire, public userData: UserData) {
    this.smartTableData = this.af.database.list('events/' + this.userData.user.uid + '/contacts');
  }
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code for the operation that you want to success, but that fails.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added the code that done have access when this rules are set.

Comment: This should not fail as long as the user is authenticated when you attach the listener. If you are certain you are only attaching the listener after the user has been authenticated, can you set up a jsbin that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think the way you have setup your rules will work due to the way rules cascade.

But based on what i think u need, the following setup should do the trick.

```
"rules": {
     "events":{
         "$uid": {
             ".write": "$uid === auth.uid || root.child('admin').hasChild(auth.uid)",
             ".read": "(auth != null && auth.uid == $uid) || root.child('admin').hasChild(auth.uid)"
        }
    }
},
```